# Will the accept vote on the answer be removed upon user deletion?

Tags: support, voting, deleted-accounts

It is known that user votes are removed when account is deleted. Is accept of the answer included in this?

To be more clear, OP has accepted an answer. Later when their account is deleted, will the tick also disappear along with the votes cast by them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> OP has accepted an answer. Later when their account is deleted, will
>   the tick also disappear along with the votes cast by them?

No. Accepted answers will still be marked as accepted.

Additionally, reputation points (+15) gained from accepting the answer will not be removed (lost).

Example: [How to use a custom debug.keystore in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371098/how-to-use-a-custom-debug-keystore-in-delphi)